# Given the following moment generating function, find P(X=0): Mx(t) = e^t

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, moment-generating-functions

I don't really know how to go about this. I can find the expected value and variance but I don't think they help me in this situation... I tried using the definition of the MGT but I'm not really sure how to get P(x) out of it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You have clearly put some work into this. Can you show us exactly what you tried?

Comment: Hint: $X$ is a degenerate random variable.